# How to make the content of a div to be in center

Tags: css

in this div, the content's top is higher than the bottom, please tell me what to do now..

```
.dtestContactDet{

border-bottom:1px solid  #D7D7DE;
border-bottom:1px solid  #D7D7DE ;
-khtml-border-bottom:1px solid  #D7D7DE;


-moz-border-radius:1px solid  #D7D7DE;

-webkit-border-bottom:1px solid  #D7D7DE;


}
```

Comment: can you post the html too please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pasting the HTML would help too. The question is a little bit vague, please explain. Do you mean you want to center the div or do you really want to center what's inside the div? If it's the former:

```
.dtestContactDet{
  text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As [leonel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/912895/leonel/) said. That's the [preview](http://jsfiddle.net/FpnEH/).